# Disabling Scrolling on iOS 12 - Tried and True Stack Overflow Solution Has To Execute Twice To Work

Tags: javascript, ios, scroll, disable

I'm having an issue disabling scrolling on iOS 12.0.1.  There's an old post (4770025) outlining solutions on how to disable scrolling however the system won't let me add a comment to it explaining my iOS 12 issue.  It says I must have a 50 reputation to do so.  My only way to raise the issue is to ask a question.

[Old Post:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily)

The solution from the old post I'm using (the most popular solution w/634 votes) was penned by gblazex.  His solution worked fine for me on iOS up through version 11.  However last night when I upgraded to 12.0.1 it suddenly broke.  gblazex's working demo that implements his solution also fails on iOS 12 (Safari, Chrome, FF).  However, when playing around w/the demo I discovered that when I press the disable scrolling button twice it "magically" works, the scrolling is disabled.

gblazex's Working Demo:

output.jsbin.com/xatidu/4/

I'm wondering why a second run of the code is necessary to make it work?  I also want everyone to know if they are running into this problem in production a temporary work-around would be to run the code a second time.  I adjusted my code to run twice and it fixed my application's issues w/iOS 12.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you perhaps update Safari/Chrome/FF when updating your phone?

Comment: New observation.  In the working demo mentioned above, if I hit the disable scrolling button once it still scrolls in iOS 12.  However, if I hit it a second time the scrolling is successfully disabled.  Odd.  I applied this same concept, calling my own code twice and it worked.  Disturbing.  What is going on???

Comment: Mars: Good question!  Undoubtedly Safari was updated but not Chrome or FF.

Comment: Try adding your new observation to your question (edit), or even editing the question to focus on why the double click

Comment: Mars: Great suggestion, I've reworded the initial inquiry.  :-D